# MoveIt Move only one Joint

Tags: ros, joint, moveit, move-group-interface

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everybody,

Can someone tell me, how to move only one joint with MoveIt -  Move Group Interface and not the end-effector pose.

Has someone experiences and can give me a some tips?

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/273732/moveit-move-only-one-joint/) by [sawsi](https://answers.ros.org/users/31405/sawsi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 38 on 2017-10-21

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Get the current joint values from your moveGroup (C++ version):

```
std::vector<double> joints;
joints = moveGroup.getCurrentJointValues();
```

Set whatever joint you want to change:

```
joints.at(y) = x.x;
```

Send the move command:

```
moveGroup.setJointValueTarget(joints);
moveGroup.move();
```

---

Originally posted by [AndyZe](https://answers.ros.org/users/21281/andyze/) with karma: 2331 on 2017-10-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [v4hn](https://answers.ros.org/users/4809/v4hn/) on 2017-10-22**:
+1 This is probably the simplest way to do it.
However, note that this actually sends target values for *all* joints in the group, using the current values as target. This is slightly different (depending on the driver) compared to requesting only *one* joint to move.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Add a move group, i.e. "JointModelGroup", in your srdf that contains only this one joint.

Afterwards you can set a joint target for this group via [setJointValueTarget](http://docs.ros.org/kinetic/api/moveit_ros_planning_interface/html/classmoveit_1_1planning__interface_1_1MoveGroupInterface.html#a71e3819bd31711dcb81c18305ca9a521).

---

Originally posted by [v4hn](https://answers.ros.org/users/4809/v4hn/) with karma: 2950 on 2017-10-21

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1